Firebase Authentication with Google Sign In on Flutter iOS - SignInWithIdp are blocked
I'm building a Flutter app that targets both iOS and Android. In this app, I'm signing up my users with Firebase Authentication. My Android app works great: I can sign up a user using the Android emulator, no problem on this side. But on iOS, I can tap my Sign in with Google button, the OAuthConsent screen appears and is working, but when I select my user, I receive this error:
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/internal-error] Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information." UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, NSLocalizedDescription=An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information., NSUnderlyingError=0x302a666a0 {Error Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x302a69710 {Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=403 "(null)" UserInfo={data={length = 774, bytes = 0x7b0a2020 22657272 6f72223a 207b0a20 ... 5d0a2020 7d0a7d0a }, data_content_type=application/json; charset=UTF-8}}, FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey={
    code = 403;
    details =     (
                {
            "@type" = "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo";
            domain = "googleapis.com";
            metadata =             {
                consumer = "projects/123456789012";
                service = "identitytoolkit.googleapis.com";
            };
            reason = "API_KEY_SERVICE_BLOCKED";
        }
    );
    errors =     (
                {
            domain = global;
            message = "Requests to this API identitytoolkit method google.cloud.identitytoolkit.v1.AuthenticationService.SignInWithIdp are blocked.";
            reason = forbidden;
        }
    );
    message = "Requests to this API identitytoolkit method google.cloud.identitytoolkit.v1.AuthenticationService.SignInWithIdp are blocked.";
    status = "PERMISSION_DENIED";
}}}}

Now, in my opinion, the most important line here is this one:

Requests to this API identitytoolkit method google.cloud.identitytoolkit.v1.AuthenticationService.SignInWithIdp are blocked.

So I believe there must be something wrong with my Cloud Storage configuration. Here's what I checked and believe is OK:

I've set up my project with the FlutterFire CLI
I have the latest GoogleService-Info.plist added to my Xcode Project
The user I'm trying to sign up is registered as a test user of the OAuth screen
My client ID for iOS looks like it is properly configured, the ID and URL scheme I can find there are also reflected in the GoogleService-Info.plist…

Truly, I have no idea why I have this error. I googled it, and there are only two answers I've found:

Create a new Firebase project. IMO, this is not an acceptable solution. What if I was 5 years into production with an Android app with 5M users. I would never entertain this idea. Besides, I have no guarantee that setting all of this up a second time would actually solve the issue. So I'm looking for an answer hopefully better than that.
Enable Identity Toolkit API to your API restrictions. Apparently this is from a documentation of yore. I don't know what I should do with this exactly…

Thank you in advance to anyone that can point me in the right direction!

OK, I've finally found an answer.
This error basically means that the key the app is using isn't authorized for Firebase Authentication. More precisely, the key is restricted, and it isn't allowed to access Identity Toolkit API.
So, my issue was that I wasn't looking at the right key.
Step 1: Finding the keys
To find the keys used by your firebase project head over to Google Cloud -> APIs & Services -> Credentials. Your keys are listed in the API Keys section. OAuth 2.0 Client IDs are not keys!
Step 2: Identifying the key used by your application
If you've configured your project using FlutterFire CLI, you can look at firebase_options.dart to find your platform's key (apiKey).
Step 3: Find the key in Google Cloud
Use the Show Key button to find the key the matches your platform's key. Once you've found it, know that this key is the one that manages all the Google Cloud permissions for your app's platform.
Step 3.a: Rename the key with an obvious name
The main issue I had was that this key was named "Google Maps iOS", which was very misleading because it was also used for Firebase.
Step 4: Edit permissions
Select your key and look at the API restrictions section. You want to add Identity Toolkit API.
Authentication should work now. 
